# Contact Form 7 - Show image on successful send?

Tags: plugins, plugin-contact-form-7

I am running Contact 7 form, and looks good for my needs.

I have [added it to Wordpress](http://www.dekho.com.au/?page_id=727), for people to suggest ideas for our product.

When users send an idea, they are given a message to say thanks.
This message is configurable via the settings for the form in wp-admin

[image]

Does anyone know how I could get Mr Burns to appear once they have successfully sent an idea?
i.e. Make a picture visible, and ideally place the picture to the side of the contact form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the "Your message was sent successfully. Thanks." message with-in the the form's edit page at the bottom
[image]

so add something like this:

```
Your message was sent successfully. Thanks.</p>
<p><a href="http://pages.sbcglobal.net/bluealbino/SYP/images/mrburns-oh.gif"><img width="234" height="369" alt="" src="http://pages.sbcglobal.net/bluealbino/SYP/images/mrburns-oh.gif" class="alignnone"></a></p>
```

**Update:**
Just tried and it works with this exact code.